# My file is getting shorter and I don't know why

Tags: ruby

I have a requirement where I need to edit part of xml file and save it, but in my code some part of the xml file it not saving.I want to modify `<mtn:ttl>4</mtn:ttl>` to `<mtn:ttl>9</mtn:ttl>`, this part is getting modified in the below code but while writting/saving only part of file is getting chaged or the format of the file is getting chaged, can any one tell me how to solve this? original xml file size is 79kb but after editing and saving its becoming 78kb...

```
require "rexml/text"
require "rexml/document"
include REXML
File.open("c://conf//cad-mtn-config.xml") do |config_file|
  # Open the document and edit the file
  config = Document.new(config_file)
  if testField.to_s.match(/<mtn:ttl>/)
    config.root.elements[4].elements[11].elements[1].elements[1].elements[1].elements[8].text="9"
    # Write the result to a new file.
    formatter = REXML::Formatters::Default.new
    File.open("c://mtn-3//mtn-2.2//conf//cad-mtn-config.xml", 'w') do |result|
      formatter.write(config, result)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: REXML strips unnecessary spaces from your xml file which makes it smaller.

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without knowing exactly what about the file is getting changed. Instead of just comparing the sizes, can you compare the contents? Maybe with the [FC](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fc.mspx?mfr=true) command, since it looks like you're on Windows? If `FC /w` (the 'compress white space') option shows no differences, then @yossi's comment is the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your trying to use regular expressions, why not just use rexml? The only requirement is that you need to know where the namespace is located online.  Note if it were not mtn:ttl and just ttl you would not need the namespace.

```
require 'rexml/document'

file_path="path to file"
contents=File.new(file_path).read

xml_doc=REXML::Document.new(contents)
xml_doc.add_namespace('mtn',"http://url to mtn namespace")
xml_doc.root.elements.each('mtn:ttl') do |element|
     element.text="9"
end

File.open(file_path,"w") do |data|
   data<<xml_doc
 end
```

Comment: Even with the above code the file's size is becoming 78kb, but it should remain as 79kb itself.... Please help me soon... I need to modify the file and save it, so that other contents of the files are not changed

Comment: Why does the file size matter?  You can delete a new line character and end up with a smaller file.